# Trigger with multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to make a trigger that are going to take a value from one table and then make a subtraction with an other value in another table.

The trigger are going to operate in a table could (deposit), and then I would like to take the value that the user just inserted to the deposit table and subtract it with a value in another table(account). I have no problem to get following code to compile:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER aifer_insättning 
AFTER INSERT
ON deposit
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.belopp is not null)
BEGIN
UPDATE account SET SALDO = saldo + :new.belopp;
end;
/
```

But of course this update al the rows in the table account. I have tried everything to make it work with only one row, but I can´t get it. Does anyone have some suggestion hove I can resolve this?
Here is my tables:

```
SQL> desc account
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------
 KNR                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 KTNR                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 REGDATUM                                  NOT NULL DATE
 SALDO                                              NUMBER(10,2)

SQL> desc deposit
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------
 RADNR                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(9)
 PNR                                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(11)
 KNR                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 BELOPP                                             NUMBER(10,2)
 DATUM                                     NOT NULL DATE
```

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that the common column KNR is the primary key of ACCOUNT, I think the code you want is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER aifer_insättning 
    AFTER INSERT
    ON deposit
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (new.belopp is not null)
BEGIN
    UPDATE account a
    SET a.SALDO = a.saldo + :new.belopp
    WHERE a.knr - :new.knr;
end;
/
```

Note that I have added a table alias to make the code clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you just need to add a `where` clause to the `update` statement in the trigger body? Or am I missing something?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER aifer_insättning 
AFTER INSERT
ON insättning
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.belopp is not null)
BEGIN
UPDATE konto SET SALDO = saldo + :new.belopp
WHERE knr in (SELECT knr FROM insättning);
end;
/
I think this code would be the right solution, but I can´t get it work and I have no idé why it doesn´t work

Answer (score 0):

delimiter $$ 
create trigger ss_ss before update on employee 
for each row 
begin 
  update consignee set 
    created_by = NEW.employee_pin 
    where created_by = OLD.employee_pin; 
end 
$$ 
delimiter ;

**NOTE->** employee and consignee are two tables

Answer (score 0):

**

### Generate Triggers for all Tables

**
Well, I did this originally to generate triggers for all tables in a database to audit data changes, and that is simple enough, just move the entire row from the deleted table to a mirrored audit table.

But someone wanted to track activity on tables, so it's a little more simple.  Here we create one log table, and any time a DML operation occurs, it is written there.

Enjoy

```
USE Northwind GO

CREATE TABLE LOG_TABLE (
  Add_dttm datetime DEFAULT (GetDate()),
  TABLE_NAME sysname,
  Activity char(6)
);

GO

DECLARE
  @sql varchar(8000),
  @TABLE_NAME sysname SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT @TABLE_NAME = MIN(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables

WHILE @TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT @sql = 'CREATE TRIGGER
  [' + @TABLE_NAME + '_Usage_TR]
    ON [' + @TABLE_NAME +'] '
    + 'FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS '
    + 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) '
  + 'INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE
  (TABLE_NAME,Activity)
  SELECT ''' + @TABLE_NAME + ''', ''INSERT''' + ' '
  + 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) '
  + 'INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE (TABLE_NAME,Activity) SELECT '''
  + @TABLE_NAME + ''', ''UPDATE''' + ' '
  + 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) '
  + 'INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE (TABLE_NAME,Activity)
  SELECT ''' + @TABLE_NAME + ''',
  ''DELETE''' + ' GO'

  SELECT @sql EXEC(@sql)

  SELECT @TABLE_NAME = MIN(TABLE_NAME)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
  WHERE TABLE_NAME > @TABLE_NAME
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```